# How to obtain the index of the certain data type in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing

I have a list containing string, int, and float data.

For example:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 1, 2, 3.5, 4.6]
```

I want to have the float data index such as `[4,5]` from the example above.

How can I do that?

Comment: Which part of this don't you understand: how to check the type of the value, or how to build a list?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I want to have the indices of the float data type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep it simple:

```
[i for i, x in enumerate(a) if isinstance(x, float)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `list comprehensions` to solve this -

```
index_float = [i for i in range(len(a)) if type(a[i])==float]
print(index_float)
     [4, 5]
```

Depending upon the index of which `datatype` you want, you can equate it to `type()`

Answer (score 1):

You could find them using a list comprehension:

```py
[i for i in range(len(a)) if isinstance(a[i], float)]
```

Result:

```py
[4, 5]
```

Comment: `range(len(x))` is not very Pythonic 

Comment: I agree that using `enumerate` (Kirby's answer) is indeed better.